# Correspondece chess on agreed openings

Tags: correspondence-chess

I would like to play correspondace chess, but in order to use it as training for my openning repertoire, I want to agree with the oponent which opening to use.

For example, We bith give a list of openings/variations and agree in which position start playing. Is any website with this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Red hot pawn](http://www.redhotpawn.com/), you can create an open invite with any starting position you like. With free account, the number of simultaneous unfinished games is limited to 6.

Comment: I tested Red Hot Pawn and Gameknot. I will select Red Hot Pawn as the Answer, because it allows to select the position from the begining.

Answer (score 0):

Gameknot allows [mini-tournaments](http://gameknot.com/start-minit.pl) to specify a starting position for all games in the tournament. This is a popular way to explore openings; I do it frequently.

Mini-tournament participation does require that you've completed a few games on the site already though.

Answer (score 0):

On [Chess.com](http://www.chess.com/) you may set an open [challenge](http://www.chess.com/echess/create_game) with a predetermined position (to choose from a list, click the "Show more options" box), and if one game is not enough you even have the option of joining a [tournament](http://www.chess.com/tournaments/myhome), some of which have the starting position of a certain opening or variation.

With a free account, you are allowed to issue as many challenges as you want, join as many official tournaments as you want and join one non-official tournament. If you want to create your own, you must go premium.